# Install Oracle on Mac OS X Lion 10.8

Tags: installation, osx-lion

I have no experience with Oracle but need to install it on my Mac so that I can test pulling data from an Oracle database. I already have Apache, PHP, MySQL installed but have no idea where to start with Oracle.

Can someone help me get setup with Oracle?

Cheers

Comment: There's no release of Oracle Database for Mac OS

Comment: @Mat Is there a work around or anyway of getting it to work?

Comment: Look at installing a VM hosting Linux, and install it on there

Comment: Using a virtual machine with Windows or Linux (or Solaris/x86).

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to install VirtualBox (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), it's free and should take a couple of minutes.

Then download a VirtualBox image file at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html. It's free for development, but it's 4GB, so you'll need a good connection or some patience. It contains a fully set up Oracle database, no need to install or configure anything.

Oracle is resource hungry, so I wouldn't run the database server all the time, only when developing. Once you finished, you can stop the VirtualBox.